# Processing an image with Open CV every n seconds

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi

I'm writing a program using OpenCV 3.4 and Python 3. I also use a Raspberry pi 3 and a PiCamera.
My problem is that I have to process the last frame from a video recorded in real time from picamera every 2 or 3 seconds.

```
import cv2
from time import sleep
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    suc, img=cam.read()
    #operation on image, it's not important
    cv2.imshow(...)
```

I've a code similar to this.
This code works really well, but raspberry continues to process the last frame of the video many times for seconds.
I want process only 1 time every 2 or 3 seconds.
I've tried with time.sleep(2) in the while loop but it doesn't work because then the video is not in real time. I've searched a lot on the internet and I think that picamera continues to record and when the 2 seconds are passed, my program processes the frame after and not the last frame recorded by the camera.
On the internet I've found a function called VideoCapture.Grab but I don't understand how it works and if I have to use it.
I've find this other question that is very similar to mine 
[How to capture a picture after every 5 seconds of camera using opencv python and Raspbery Pi 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49278087/how-to-capture-a-picture-after-every-5-seconds-of-camera-using-opencv-python-and?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
but the second part of code is cut or similar and I can't understand.
Thank you all.

Comment: Put the `suc,img=cam.read()` line after the `time.sleep(2)` line.

Comment: Have any of the posted answers solved your issue?

Comment: I think the issue here is that OpenCV buffers up to 5 frames, so if you don't read for 2 seconds, the first 4-5 frames you read after that will be up to 2 seconds old. The solution is to continually call `grab()` to keep  the frames refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually count time using `time.time()`.

```
from time import time
import cv2

# Create a new VideoCapture object
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Initialise variables to store current time difference as well as previous time call value
previous = time()
delta = 0

# Keep looping
while True:
    # Get the current time, increase delta and update the previous variable
    current = time()
    delta += current - previous
    previous = current

    # Check if 3 (or some other value) seconds passed
    if delta > 3:
        # Operations on image
        # Reset the time counter
        delta = 0

    # Show the image and keep streaming
    _, img = cam.read()
    cv2.imshow("Frame", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and easy solution:

In python, `time.time()` grabs the current time in seconds since January 1st, 1970.  In your while loop, if you just grab the current time and compare it to the time that you last grabbed a frame, then you can check if 2 seconds has passed and then decide to 'keep' your frame as you've mentioned.  You can try the following code:

```
import cv2
import time
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
last_recorded_time = time.time() # this keeps track of the last time a frame was processed
while True:
    curr_time = time.time() # grab the current time

    # keep these three statements outside of the if statement, so we 
    #     can still display the camera/video feed in real time
    suc, img=cam.read()
    #operation on image, it's not important
    cv2.imshow(...)

    if curr_time - last_recorded_time >= 2.0: # it has been at least 2 seconds
        # NOTE: ADD SOME STATEMENTS HERE TO PROCESS YOUR IMAGE VARIABLE, img

        # IMPORTANT CODE BELOW
        last_recorded_time = curr_time
```

Notice that I added 4 lines of code and changed 1 (`from time import sleep` to `import time`).  I hope this helps!  It won't pause your program or slow it down at all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it doen't work; Actually now the program stop for 2 seconds and ok, but then processed a old frame and not the last frame of the picamera... there are a lot of delay / gap from real time video of camera and image processing... I'm looking for something that skip all the frames in the 2 or 3 seconds when the program is stopped

Comment: whitout any sleep or time.time() ecc ecc the program processes real time video, when I use some function similar to these there is a big gap between real time video and image processing... I want to stop for 2 second and then process the real time frame and not an old frame

Comment: Ah okay, I updated the code in my post.  I think what you may be referring to is that the `cv2.imshow(...)` only runs on the frames that are selected, instead of every frame, so it "appears" as if it stops for 2 seconds.  Basically, just move the `cv2.imshow(...)` and `suc, img=cam.read()` before the if statement.